# fakeroot permission denied when compiling kernel

Tags: kernel, permissions, compiling

I'm trying to compile a kernel. I've gone to the kernel tree root and did as [instructed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel#Building_the_kernel):

```
lz@air:~/Downloads/linux-4.15.4$ fakeroot debian/rules clean
/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 175: debian/rules: Permission denied
lz@air:~/Downloads/linux-4.15.4$ sudo fakeroot debian/rules clean
/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 175: debian/rules: Permission denied
```

I also couldn't find about this particular error on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply doing

```
chmod a+x debian/rules
```

solved the problem